# Whats wrong with django url mapping?

Tags: django, django-urls

i have this url in my urls.py

```
url(r'^filter/$', views.filterTest, name="filter-test"),
```

and making GET request like

```
/filter/?month=2
```

but response is `Page not found (404)`

dont know whats wrong with that ?

Comment: Remove the `?` in the url: `'^filter/$'`

Comment: @timmy changed the url but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the request without the trailing slash?

```
/filter?month=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^filter/(?P<month>\d+)$', views.filterTest, name="filter-test"),
```

will find a url like yoursite.com/filter/02/

In your view, find the month value in the request.GET object